# Webpack dynamic requires with module path

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a similar use case as the hybrid-routing example provided in the webpack source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/hybrid-routing

In this example, all of the route destinations are located in the same relative directory.  In my use case, the code for the route destinations are separate modules that are included via npm.  I rearranged the example in this fork to illustrate the basic structure: https://github.com/butchpeters/webpack/tree/master/examples/hybrid-routing

The biggest change is in router.js (line 18) where I am trying to bundle a module path instead of a relative one.  This doesn't seem to work; however, the relative path 'bundle!./node_modules/' + name + '/' + name + 'Page' does seem to work.

Looking for some guidance on the proper way to do this with webpack.